# My post permalinks are always the same in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, slug

I noticed all my new posts have the same permalink. I noticed it was the same as my sticky post so I removed that setting but it didn't change anything. If I create a post called "Permalink Test" I would expect my url to be like `/blog/permalink-test` but instead it the permalink for another post.

I tried resetting my permalinks in the settings but that didn't do anything either.

Comment: Have you tried reuploading (ftp) the core WordPress files. A corrupt uploaded file could potentially cause. Failing that, you should disable all plugins and try reaching the permalink structure. If it works reactivate your plugins one at a Tim to identify which is causing the problem.

Comment: I tried deactivating plugins and regenerating the permalinks in settings but the problem is stiil there.

Comment: Ok, then perhaps you need to repair the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try repairing your database via the built-in but little known WordPress database repair tool

You can do this by adding the following line in your wp-config.php file. Add it just before ‘That’s all, stop editing! Happy blogging’ line wp-config.php.

define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);

Once you have done that, you can see the settings by visiting this page:

http://www.yoursite.com/wp-admin/maint/repair.php

More info here:
http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-error-establishing-a-database-connection-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

Turns out one of my devs used a generic var in his metabox php and was freaking WP out...